# 'sudo cd' don't work when I try to change my current work dir to which I don't have right to access

Tags: centos7

Described in the title.
In other linux system, it works. But it fails when I'm trying in my new linux.
Centos 7.
So I think there maybe some settings that could make it work.Or there maybe something wrong with my linux.

Comment: `sudo cd foo` has no chance to "work", the `cd` is done for the process that sudo starts, doesn't affect anything else (like your current shell).

Comment: Note: This question is off topic for SO and will most probably be closed. It is more appropriate for https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

`cd` is a builtin shell command. `sudo` only works with executables. To achieve `change directory`, you could do `sudo sh -c 'cd <dirname>'` but as soon as the shell exits, you will return to previous state.

Comment: Got it. `sudo sh -c 'cd <dirname>'` this works for me. Thank you.

Comment: @Jasonling maybe now you can mark the answer. It will help others :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to make yourself a super user and move into that directory as follows.

```
sudo -i
cd /path_for_directory
```

After your work is done, type exit to get back to normal user.

```
exit
```

Comment: Thanks. `sudo -i` this command change my current user to root. But this is not what I want.